# PlayBook app wont make http rpc calls. HTTP request error

Tags: air, flash-builder, blackberry-playbook

I have a simple app written in air using Flash Builder Burrito that makes rpc calls to a webservice. The app works perfectly when it is run in a shockwave window, but it doesn't make the http call on the PlayBook simulator.

`responder.token = ph.verifySettings(txtServer.text, Number(txtPort.text), txtUser.text, txtPass.text);`

From closer inspection the request is sent but the response is not received. Flash builder isn't showing the request in the Network monitor though. I can do the Test Operation from Flash Builder and see that it works and I can run it with the launch method set to desktop and it works as expected.

This is the error that I am getting

`[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost:37813/ws/verifySettings?hostport=ph.no.de&https=N&id=4F861F44-6267-6379-E80E-0156CED4E259" errorID=2032]. URL: http://ph.no.de/ws/verifySettings"] messageId="5C754C53-64C3-61D9-4580-0156CF05B7E3" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't use the network monitor with the PlayBook simulator.

```
var http:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
            http.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, function (event:ResultEvent):void {
                trace("data " + event.result);
            });
            http.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, function (event:FaultEvent):void {
                trace("error " + event);
            });

            http.url = "http://google.com";
            http.method = "GET";
            http.resultFormat = "text";

            http.send();
```

This fails if the Network Monitor is running and works if the Network Monitor is turned off.

Comment: I can confirm this, very strange. Ate up a lot of my time. Thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: I submitted the bug to BlackBerry. Hopefully they will fix this. I spent a few hours on this one.